# How to render a Drupal 7 menu structure with divs instead of lists

Tags: php, drupal-7, navigation

I want to change the output of the Drupal 7 menu structure which is like:

`<?php print render($primary_nav); ?>`

outputs:

```
<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="first expanded">
    <a title="" href="lorem">Lorem</a>
    <ul class="menu nav">
      <li class="first leaf"><a title="" href="/lorem">Lorem</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/ipsum">Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/dolor">Dolor</a></li>
  <li class="expanded"><a title="" href="/sit">Sit</a>
    <ul class="menu nav">
      <li class="first leaf"><a title="" href="/sit">Amet</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/consectetur">Consectetur</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

how could I have instead of the `ul` and `li` the menu rendered with `div`s.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I feel curious... why do you want to do so?

I guess you should try to make a modified copy of 'render' function and call it instead.

**EDIT**

The print "function" in PHP just outputs the argument received. I guess you should define your own php function, namely print_menu_as_div:

```
function print_menu_as_div($primary_nav) { 
    $htmlCode = '<div class="myOwnMenuClass">';
...

/*Generate your HTML code here to display your 
menu items and append to $htmlCode*/

...

    $htmlCode .= '</div>';

    return $htmlCode; 
}
```

Then instad of:

```
<?php print render($primary_nav); ?>
```

write:

```
<?php print print_menu_as_div($primary_nav); ?>
```

Hope it helps ;)